# Adding event handler in style

Tags: silverlight

I have 8 HyperlinkButton on my silverlight application. 
I want to call method HyperlinkButtonClick_Event when each of them will be clicked.

Can i do it on style ? 
If 'no' so how can i do it without adding the method explicitly on each of the HyperlinkButton instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using something like this in your style:

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
```

And using a Command, such as a DelegateCommand, with an Execute action replacing your HyperlinkButtonClick_Event code.
This is also obviously going to require you to have the datacontext set correctly for each of your buttons...

The DelegateCommand in it's **VERY** simplest form:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;
    private Action<object> executeAction;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
        this.executeAction = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.executeAction(parameter);
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute(parameter);
    }
}
```

You can find implementations of this everywhere, from SO to MSDN...

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public MyCheckBox()
    {
        this.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MyCheckBox_Click);    
    }

    void MyCheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (sender as CheckBox);
    }
}

<foo:mycheckbox ................/>
```

Define your own class and use the foo:mycheckbox in style file.